# Weird cursor movements while inserting with vim and auto-formatting enabled

Tags: vim, latex-suite

I am using vim, along with latex-suite, to edit LaTeX documents. I recently added 'a' to my formatoptions since I was getting annoyed by `gwap`ing my paragraphs all the time and noticed some extremely weird behaviour. On certain lines in LaTeX files (as far as I know it's only LaTeX files), each inserted character produces two right-movements. Thus, if the line contains:

```
abcdef
```

And I insert the text '123' before the 'a', the line produced is:

```
a1bc2de3f
```

So that's one right movement *before* inserting the character, and one afterwards. Now, as far as I can work out, the lines on which this occurs are:

1. indented
2. wrapped from a previous line.

There are definitely some weird interactions going on between the auto-formatting and various other things I have set, but I can't work out precisely what they are. First of all, the problem appears not to happen in non-LaTeX files, so I suspect latex-suite has something to do with it. Second, I am using `copyindent`, and although this problem still appears in latex files with `nocopyindent`, if I open a new file, enable copyindent, create a line that wraps and indent it (so the second line also gets indented) for instance:

```
    here is a super long line that we will pretend gets wrapped in my
    vim set-up
```

And then insert '123' before 'vim', I get:

```
    here is a super long line that we will pretend gets wrapped in my
v123im set-up
```

That is, the second line has been unindented (incorrectly - doing a == will reindent it) and, presumably as a result, the text has been inserted one character to the right of where I wanted it. So my guess is that what's happening in latex files is two or more formatting regimes all trying to do things with the line, perhaps unindenting then reindenting it, resulting in madness.

Presumably you will want to see [my vimrc](http://fishface.org.uk/static/stuff/.vimrc) and will want to know that I'm using gvim 7.3 for windows, and some version of latex-suite from about a year ago (it appears not to have any version information)

Comment: Your vimrc looks fine to me. Could you post the content of that latex-suite or point us at the correct version?

Comment: I've located my original download of latex-suite - the version number is 1.8.23, but it appears to be a git snapshot: vim-latex-1.8.23-20120125.768-git8b62284.tar. You could look at this snapshot on their [repository](http://vim-latex.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=vim-latex/vim-latex;a=summary), but I'm not sure if this will help, since it's a rather large plugin. I must also confess that I have edited it in place to fix a few bugs, but am all but certain these should not interact in this way. I should probably check/update latex-suite, but it'll take a bit of time.

Comment: Do you have spurious spaces (moving cursor to right) at end of your vim macros ?

Comment: Nope, that should all be in order. However I can't really test this any more as I'm no longer using autoformatting nor latex-suite...